# Displaying JSON text in foreign language

Tags: ios, json, twitter, character, loading

I am making a program that show a tweet.
Basically this is how it works.

1. Access the twitter json feed using the api.twitter.com: [url](https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=YunaKim_Facts&count=1)
2. Parse and display.

However, as you can see, the [texts/tweets](https://twitter.com/YunaKim_Facts) are in Korean, so the json file contains something like this `\ud329\ud2b8\ub97c` instead of Korean `트위터`. What is this character representation called?

Now, I can successfully load the above JSON to my app, but if I display it on a `textView`, will it be displayed in Korean or in this representation `\ud329\ud2b8\ub97c`?

FYI, I don't want to use Twitter library for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use NSUTF8StringEncoding, something along the line of following should work:

```
NSString* query = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:queryString] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&errorStr];         
NSData *resultJson = [query dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];          
if( query )
{
// do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The stored text is encoded as Unicode char codes.

To get text from it, you need the `JSON.parse` (JS function) or similar. Though you did not mention which language you program is written in, there are JSON parsers in most of them.

Comment: It was written in objective-c. Thanks for your answer :)